# How can I feed a document section by section onto LangChain's OpenAI API and get a final answer based on every section?

Tags: python, document, streamlit, openai-api, langchain

Basically, I am using Streamlit's file_uploader to upload a .txt document, which is much longer than the ChatGPT token limit. So far, I have a working prototype which uses a text splitter, embeddings, and a vectorstore database to come up with an answer based on similarities in the document. However, it is not very accurate.

So I want to feed the document into ChatGPT, token limit by token limit, with some overlap, get multiple answers from each time I feed it in, and combine all the answers to have one final answer, to hopefully improve the accuracy.

When I look online, I see things like use "map_reduce" as the chain type, but everything is storing the data as a vectorstore with embeddings and using relevant splits to create an answer.

Is there a way to feed the raw document into the OpenAI API section by section, and generate a final cumulative answer?